# Coding a calculator

Tags: android

I'm just a beginner in coding using Android studio and I have a couple of questions in coding a calculator (The calculator is used to only compute carbon emissions so it varies a little bit compared to an actual calculator):

- How do I have a clear all button?
- How do I add all of the
  products that the user has calculated and show its sum? (Kind of like
  how those tracking expenses kind of app)

This is my code so far:

```
package com.carschoolingpromo.scires.carschooling;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calculator extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

        Button caremissionscheck = findViewById(R.id.checkcar);
        caremissionscheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent tocarbonemissions = new Intent(Calculator.this, CarbonEmissions.class);
                startActivity(tocarbonemissions);
            }
        });

        Button distancecheck = findViewById(R.id.checkdestination);
        distancecheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent checkdistance = new Intent(Calculator.this, DistancesList.class);
                startActivity(checkdistance);
            }
        });

        final Button multiply =(Button)findViewById(R.id.multiply);
        final EditText num1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.carboninput);
        final EditText num2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.distanceinput);
        final TextView ans =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
        final TextView carbontotal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sumofcarbon);

        multiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                double n1 = Double.parseDouble(num1.getText().toString());
                double n2 = Double.parseDouble(num2.getText().toString());

                ans.setText(String.valueOf(n1*n2));


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `How do I have a clear all button?` Create a button. Then, when it is pressed, clear what you want it to clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I have a clear all button?

You need to create a new button in the layout file, and get a reference of it in your code, then set a click listener on that reference. Then in the `onClick()` implementation you will clear your 2 edit texts and 2 text views, something like this:

```java
final Button clearAll =(Button)findViewById(R.id.clear_all);
clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            num1.setText("");
            num2.setText("");

            ans.setText("");
            carbontotal.setText("");
        }
    });
```

> How do I add all of the products that the user has calculated and show its sum? (Kind of like how those tracking expenses kind of app)

For this you need to use some sort of a way to show a list on your UI, I suggest you look into [this tutorial by google to creating lists](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)